Getting an error when trying to import Keras
I have Keras installed and optree installed, and it still says "To use Keras, you need to have optree installed. Install it via pip install optree"
Even when trying to run this code:
import keras
print(keras.__version__)

I am still getting this error:
"Traceback (most recent call last):
    File , line 1, in <module>
    import keras
    File , line 4, in <module>
    from keras.api import DTypePolicy
    File , line 8, in <module>
    from keras.api import activations
    File , line 7, in <module>
    from keras.src.activations import deserialize
    File , line 1, in <module>        
    from keras.src import activations
    File , line 3, in <module>
    from keras.src.activations.activations import elu
    File , line 1, in <module>
    from keras.src import backend
    File , line 9, in <module>
    from keras.src.backend.common.dtypes import result_type
    File , line 2, in <module>
    from keras.src.backend.common.dtypes import result_type
    File , line 5, in <module>
    from keras.src.backend.common.variables import standardize_dtype
    File , line 10, in <module>
    from keras.src.utils.module_utils import tensorflow as tf
    File , line 1, in <module>  
    from keras.src.utils.audio_dataset_utils import audio_dataset_from_directory
    File , line 4, in <module>
    from keras.src.utils import dataset_utils
    File , line 9, in <module>
    from keras.src import tree
    File , line 1, in <module>   
    from keras.src.tree.tree_api import assert_same_structure
    File , line 10, in <module>  
    raise ImportError(
    ImportError: To use Keras, you need to have `optree` installed. Install it via `pip install optree`"

I have tried various different import statements and different Python versions, ans they all produce a similar error.
Does anyone know why this is happening?

And did you do what the error told you to do?

This seems like typing issues from the stack trace. Does this answer help you fix the issue?
